# Converting a visio to a JPG image

Tags: image, visio

I have a .vss type file which I want to convert to an image format (like JPG/GIF). Is it possible to do this and if so, how?

Comment: This should probably be on superuser.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not programming related and you can simply use "File > Save as..." to save as a JPG.

Comment: Thanks. This does the job. My apologies for posting it here. Didn't realise.